# Normalizing response variable for random forest regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am working on a project where I want to make a sales forecast by day for food company. They sell both bulk orders to retailers and directly to customers which means that they have both very large and very small values of sales for each transaction. I have done some basic data cleaning and feature engineering and run a host of regression algorithms including random forest regression and gradient boosting using scikit learn. I have evaluated the models using rmse and mape but all models have given terrible results. I thought about separating the sales data by grouping them by sales amount I.e large transactions >1000 and small transactions <1000. However this still gave rather poor results.

I then did a box-cox transform on the sales amount (response variable) and suddenly got much better mape if <22. Is this really logical to normalize was the response variable in this way?

Finally I could try other algorithms such as Mondrian forests but I have no experience with them and maybe misunderstanding how they would help me in this situation.

I apologize if I have missed something very basic here I am relatively inexperienced in using machine learning.

Comment: The two main measures for whether you "should" do something like scaling or normalization are, in my experience: 1) Can you translate it back to a real number for a real world prediction, and, most importantly, 2) Does the good result _generalize well to unseen data_

Comment: 1) I need to translate the values back yes. Perhaps I should also be using different evaluation metrics. 2) the good mape score was on the test data.

Comment: general rule of thumb is: As long as you're fitting a scaler on the training set and then using it to transform the test set (to avoid data leakage), and the scaler you're using doesn't violate any constraints on the real data, then if it can more accurately predict on truly unseen test data, then it's a valid use-case

Comment: Thanks, i applied the normalization (not scaler) to the sales amount in the train and test. I guess I was surprised by how much of a difference it made to the accuracy of the predictions, going from totally unpredictable to consistently between 20-30 mape. It kind of made sense, from my basic understanding of random forest, if the algorithm uses the (estimated) mean of the target variable.